# Getting an error with the click function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building an application that takes in grade and then gives the average. It also has a sort button that makes it so you can sort by the last name of the student entered and a clear button to clear the current values that are in the display array. Here is the code I have so far for the javascript file:

```
var $ = function (id) {return document.getElementById(id);}
"use strict";

var scoreArray = [];
var dispArray = []; 

var displayScores = function () {
var totalScore = 0;
var numberOfScores = 0;
var averageScore = 0;

numberOfScores = scoreArray.length;

//loop to find the total score 
for (var i=0;i<numberOfScores;i++)
{
totalScore = totalScore + scoreArray[i];
}

//find the average 
averageScore = totalScore/numberOfScores;

var st="";

//put the string in the display array
for(var i=0; i<numberOfScores;i++)
{
st += (dispArray[i]+"\n");
}

//display the average score 
$("#average_score").val(averageScore.toString());

$("#scores").val(st);
};


$("#add_button").click(function(){
var scoreNumber = parseInt( $("#score").val());
var scoreString = $("#last_name").val() + ", " + $("first_name").val() + ": " + $("#score").val();

scoreArray.push(scoreNumber);

dispArray.push(scoreString);

displayScores();

//reset the values 
$("#first_name").val("");
$("#last_name").val("");
$("#score").val("");
$("#first_name").focus();

});

//function to clear the contents of the form
$("#clear_button").click(function(){

//empty the arrays 
scoreArray=[];
dispArray=[];

//reset the values in the form 
$("#scores").val("");
$("#first_name").val("");
$("#last_name").val("");
$("average_score").val("");
$("#score").val("");

});

//function to sort the scores based on the last name that was entered
$("#sort_button").click(function(){
var mylen = scoreArray.length;

//sorting
for(var kk=0;kk<mylen;kk++)
{
    for(var aa = 1; aa<(mylen-kk);aa++)
    {
        var xp1 = dispArray[aa-1].split(" ");
        var lname1 = xp1[0];
        lname1 = lname1.slice(0, -1);

        var xp2 = dispArray[aa].split(" ");
        var lname2 = xp2[0];
        lname2 = lname2.slice(0, -1);

        if (lname1 > lname2){
            var tp1 = scoreArray[aa];
            scoreArray[aa]=scoreArray[aa-1];
            scoreArray[aa-1] = tp1;

            var tp2 = dispArray[aa];
            dispArray[aa]=dispArray[aa-1];
            dispArray[aa-1] = tp2;
        }
    }
}

//display the scores 
$("#scores").val("");
var st=" ";
for(var i=0;i<dispArray.length;i++)
{
    st += (dispArray[i]+"\n");
}

//display the sorted scores 
$("scores").val(st);
});

$("#first_name").focus();
```

It is giving the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at scores.js:38

Line 38 is the click function for the add button to add the score to the display array: $("#add_button").click(function(){

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: try debugging, console.log or alert at function start and return false, so that rest  does not work, and see if error occurs, if not then see all 3 values by consolelog,if  they are fine

Comment: My first guess would be that you are importing your script before the DOM elements you are trying to get are created. Simple fix : load your script at the end of your body, or run it when the document is ready (with a listener)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you've defined `$` as a function which returns the result of `document.getElementById()`.

What you've not accounted for is what happens if this operation finds no element, in which case it returns `null`, and there is no `.click()` method of `null`.

In short: your selector `#add_button` seems not to be finding the intended element. So check your DOM, and the presence of the element, before running that line. **Always suspect your selectors**. Either that or build in a check that only goes to `.click()` on finding an element successfully.

```
let el = $('#add_button');
if (el) el.click(...);
```

Comment: var $ = function (id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
};